# How to implement `opIndex` in higher dimensions?

Tags: d

```
struct M{
 T opIndex(uint i){ ... }
}
```

which gives me this:

```
m[i]
```

but what if I want it in two dimension so that I could do:

```
m[i][j]
```

is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do the C++ way of returning a temporary object (struct is best in D's case) which also has an index operator overload.

But a better idea in D is to go for the syntax `m[i, j]`:

```
struct S
{
    uint opIndex(uint i, uint j)
    {
        return i + j;
    }
}

void main()
{
    S s;
    assert(s[2, 3] == 5);
}
```

If you still want to use `m[i][j]`, a nested struct gives you some syntactic leeway:

```
struct S
{
    auto opIndex(uint i)
    {
        struct Temp
        {
            uint opIndex(uint j)
            {
                return i + j;
            }
        }

        return Temp();
    }
}

void main()
{
    S s;
    assert(s[2][3] == 5);
}
```

Comment: hehe, nice!  I was doing `opIndex(uint i, uint j){ return opIndex(...); }` which wasn't working.  thanks.